# Gitlab CI saves the cache again after each job using it

Tags: caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Based on Gitlab CI documentation on how cache archiving and extracting works (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-archiving-and-extracting-works):

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - echo "Hello"

job A:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mkdir vendor/
    - echo "build" > vendor/hello.txt
  cache:
    key: build-cache
    paths:
      - vendor/
  after_script:
    - echo "World"

job B:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cat vendor/hello.txt
  cache:
    key: build-cache
```

`job A` here is supposed to create the cache and `job B` is supposed to use it.

What is happening when trying this configuration though, is that `job B` once script has been executed successfully, instead of ending, is saving the cached directory again (totally useless, nothing has changed and that's not its purpose anyway):

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.3.1 (738bbe5a)
  on docker-auto-scale fa6cab46
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:40
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:c2b4a3b480bf1adee17db717baa58f4b13c59cc712cd4199706406aa09ea0566 for node:latest ...
Preparing environment
00:04
Running on runner-fa6cab46-project-[REDACTED]-concurrent-0 via runner-fa6cab46-srm-1599721095-1e9a7c0b...
Getting source from Git repository
00:03
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/[REDACTED]/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out b24f54fb as v1.3.0...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:21
Checking cache for v1-3-0_modules_app-26...
Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/[REDACTED]/v1-3-0_modules_app-26 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
[...]
Saving cache
00:43
Creating cache v1-3-0_modules_app-26...
untracked: found 66568 files                       
Uploading cache.zip to https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/[REDACTED]/v1-3-0_modules_app-26 
Created cache
[...]
```

Apart from the doc not mentioning this "feature", how to use the cache in subsequent jobs without having each of them wasting time caching it again ?

Comment: do you have only one runner on your project ?

Comment: We are using Gitlab CI on gitlab.com as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the normal behavior of the gitlab, but you can achieve what you want defining a simple policy

look at the documentation here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#inherit-global-config-but-override-specific-settings-per-job

something like

```
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - public/
    - vendor/
  policy: pull-push

job:
  cache:
    # inherit all global cache settings
    <<: *global_cache
    # override the policy
    policy: pull
```

in this example the job (called job) will only pull the cache

Comment: That was driving me nuts, didn't notice this option, thanks for your help !